# MySQL insert race condition on MyISAM only on MySQL 5.1, not 5.5 or 5.6 or InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql, centos, myisam

I'm using MySQL 5.1, PHP 5.3 and the table is MyISAM. Here's the DTD of this very fake table:

```
CREATE TABLE `temp1` (
  `value` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This script basically prints the row count for the table `temp1`, then inserts a row, then prints the row count again, then sleeps for a second and prints the row count one more time. The INSERTs are done with the `write` user and the SELECTs are done with the `read` user.

```
<?php

$value = "test";
$ro_user = "ro";
$ro_pass = "ro";
$write_user = "write";
$write_pass = "write";
$db_name = "db";

$ro_db = mysql_connect('localhost', $ro_user, $ro_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $ro_db);

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp1 WHERE value = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'", $ro_db);
var_dump(mysql_num_rows($res));

$write_db = mysql_connect('localhost', $write_user, $write_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $write_db);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO temp1 (`value`)  VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "')", $write_db);

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp1 WHERE value = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'", $ro_db);
var_dump($res);
var_dump(mysql_num_rows($res));

sleep(1);

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp1 WHERE value = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'", $ro_db);
var_dump($res);
var_dump(mysql_num_rows($res));
```

The printout are usually something like this:

```
int(12)
resource(8) of type (mysql result)
int(12)
resource(9) of type (mysql result)
int(13)
```

This seems to indicate that the `INSERT` isn't fully complete by the time the second `SELECT` query is executed. So my questions are:

- Are MySQL INSERT statements usually asynchronous? It's hard to get information about this, but I thought the answer was no.
- Are there any MySQL settings which would influence this behavior?
- Is the table engine significant here?
- Is there any possibility of caching going on which would cause this? I'm running this on a vagrant box with default settings.

Even weirder, I can't reproduce this behavior in MySQL 5.5 or 5.6, or any InnoDB table. No race condition shows up there.